# Search results that display in the form of "1 - 20 of about 65" - why the "about"?

Tags: google, search-engine, pagination

I've noticed that Google and large search engines do not display "proper" paging, but display an approximation.  For example, I tried to give a specific search on Google to return few results, as per below:

```
eating +ants in malta near the sea
```

This returned "About 71 results".

However, it only showed 2 pages in the pages at the bottom.  Considering 1 page contains 10 entries, the maximum this can actually be is somewhere in the range of 11 - 20.  Then, I clicked on page 2, and this time the total results changed to `Page 2 of 16 results`.

Just curious, any ideas why is this done?  I am assuming for performance reasons, however since it did manage to get the page count right, why was the 'About 71' so off, from the actual 16 to 71, which is a huge discrepancy?

Comment: I think the only people that know this are Google engineers.